# Laravel site is horrendously slow all of a sudden

Tags: php, debugging, caching, laravel-4, amazon-ec2

My laravel site has gone horribly slow all of a sudden.

It uses a lot of caching and I had restructured caching so commonly referenced data would be stored in permanent file caches. So theres a lot of data access happening on file cache as opposed to the database i.e. common data which doesn't change much is stored in the cache while everything else is retrieved as database queries.

However after doing that i.e. making permanent caches on my server the site speed has gone down to upto 16 seconds waiting time according to firebugs Net panel.

I've used `php artisan optimize --force` - just about every trick I can think of but to no avail. I'm not sure if its a code related issue or my amazon ec2 instance is being a mess. It works fine on my localhost though. How can I check deep to isolate code that is perhaps causing trouble here.

Comment: what cache driver are you using, if its `file` I recommend you use `mecached` according to documentation > For larger applications, it is recommended that you use an in-memory cache such as Memcached or APC. You may even configure multiple cache configurations for the same driver

Comment: I tried to setup APC but it doesn't seem to be doing much.

Comment: try memcached its very fast